# No module named 'oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849.endpoints.resource' after py2exe the code (python)

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to get my script to exe using py2exe. There is no error when converting the script but when I try to run main.exe I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "gspread\__init__.pyc", line 16, in <module>
  File "gspread\auth.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "google_auth_oauthlib\__init__.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "google_auth_oauthlib\interactive.pyc", line 24, in <module>
  File "google_auth_oauthlib\flow.pyc", line 69, in <module>
  File "google_auth_oauthlib\helpers.pyc", line 28, in <module>
  File "requests_oauthlib\__init__.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "oauthlib\oauth1\__init__.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\endpoints\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849.endpoints.resource'
```

I don't seem to be able to find said module nor install it with pip.
Sorry if the fix is actually easy, I'm pretty dumb.

Comment: did you solve it? have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use PyInstaller which will turn your code into a .exe file in the folder dist

install:

```
py -m pip install pyinstaller
```

After installing

```
cd [file path]
```

then,

```
py -m PyInstaller --onefile [script name].py
```

Comment: this worked for me but im having exceptions with the path urls